# Call to COM method blocks forever

Tags: c++, debugging, com, rpc

While debugging hanging of my application I discovered that one of COM components make call to  method of the other COM component. But the second method never gets control. The call blocks somewhere between them in rpcrt4.dll! How might this happen?

Comment: Can you show some code?  Very hard to say without some code.  Likely you've made a mistake somewhere.  COM is old an very well "settled" technology, so I doubt bugs in COM itself.

Comment: rpc with COM? not impossible but it sounds fishy... is it always blocking? If it is, your failing COM object might not support multiple threads.

Comment: Deadlock like this is often self-induced by not paying attention to the apartment requirements.  You have to pump a message loop in an STA.  You'll indeed get a deadlock in RPC if you don't, the call can't complete until the message loop dispatches the marshaled call.